# a static array does not pass values through frames

Tags: java, arrays, variables, static

I have one internal frame and one JDialog  frame. Inside this JInternal frame there is a public static String array:

```
 public static String nameofdrinks[];
```

I am adding a size and values this array from JDialog frame using an anonymous class:

```
 @Override
         public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
             //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
             if( e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
                JTextField a=(JTextField) e.getSource();
                 //showMessageDialog(null,a.getText());
                for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
                {
                    if(a.getName().equals("name_"+String.valueOf(x)) && !a.getText().equals(""))//other wise in the lost focus all of textbox values will goto same element in the array poblem
                    {


                        if(jLabel2.getText().equals("Drinks"))
                        {

                            addfoodformenue.nameofdrinks[x]=a.getText();

                        }
                        else if(jLabel2.getText().equals("Salad")) 
                        { 

                            addfoodformenue.salad[x]=a.getText(); 


                    }
                        else if(jLabel2.getText().equals("Deserts")) 
                        {  

                            addfoodformenue.desert[x]=a.getText();


                        }
                        else if(jLabel2.getText().equals("must"))
                        {

                            addfoodformenue.must[x]=a.getText();


                        }

                }

}
         }



         }
    });
```

Inside focus lost I add some values to the arrays, and it added perfectly. Then I dispose the JDialog frame and when I try to access the array elements from the internal f1rame it is null. There are no values in the all the elements of the array, what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `static` an attribute of a class but you call it from an instance, what has not much logic.

Declare your array like:

```
public String nameofdrinks[];
```

And be sure that instance reading is always the same.

**UPDATE:**

*`addfoodformenue` **is the class name** not an instance*
A class name should not start by `LOWERCASE`, please check [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

*since it is static*
you're missing the basics... **please, try to follow the instructions above**, you will se that it works...

To know **why** please [check this link](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html).

Comment: addfoodformenue is the class name not an instance.since it is static i should be able to access from any where in any class..and the array fills perfectly in the JDialog frame..but when i go try to read it from the Jinternal frame array is not filled only initialized